# Dynamic cell width of UICollectionView depending on label width

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView, that loads cells from reusable cell, which contains label. An array provides content for that label. I can resize label width depending on content width easily with sizeToFit. But I cannot make cell to fit label.

Here's the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arrayOfStats =  @[@"time:",@"2",@"items:",@"10",@"difficulty:",@"hard",@"category:",@"main"];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:     (NSInteger)section{
    return [arrayOfStats count];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return CGSizeMake(??????????);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Cell *cell = (Cell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"qw" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    // make label width depend on text width
    [cell.myLabel sizeToFit];

    //get the width and height of the label (CGSize contains two parameters: width and height)
    CGSize labelSize = cell.myLbale.frame.size;

    NSLog(@"\n width  = %f height = %f", labelSize.width,labelSize.height);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: similar sort of problem ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915443/uicollectionview-simply-fit-cell-to-width ???

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` return the size of the text

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return [(NSString*)[arrayOfStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithAttributes:NULL];
}
```

Comment: You cannot imagine how I thank you! That really works. Now I only need to resolve [cell.myLabel sizeToFit] problem, because it appears in its full size only after scrolling. But I have not been even close to your solution.

Comment: thank you for your help but I still have one issue. When I uncomment [cell.myLabel sizeToFit] I have words truncated and letters cut at the bottom but it becomes ok after I scroll (words have they normal size and letters jump up a bit). If I comment and disable [cell.myLabel sizeToFit] message (I decided to play around with IB and it works fine) I have words cut at the end and bottom. I made a screenshot http://goo.gl/HaoqQV It's not very sharp on non-retina displays but you can see that letters have cut. Your suggestion on how to solve will be really appreciated!

Comment: instead of sizeToFit, use sizeWithAttributes to get the CGSize of the text, then set the label's frame with new size.

Comment: thank you for suggestion but i still have myLabel cut at the bottom and the end. Maybe I'm wrong with implementation of you suggestion. Here's my code

Comment: `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"qw" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.myLbale.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    CGSize textSize;

    textSize = [[arrayOfStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]}];

    [cell.myLbale sizeThatFits:textSize];
    //[cell.myLbale sizeToFit];
    return cell;
}`

Comment: try this.

newLabelFrame.size = // the size from sizeWithAttributes 
cell.myLabel.frame = newLabelFrame;

Comment: cant assign `cell.myLabel.frame = newLabelFrame;` got error "Expression is not assignable". Anyways thanks for your attention, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I don't know why. Maybe you are doing something wrong. why don't you post another question about that, so people can help you ?

Comment: This is superb, but sometimes some cells are wider than they need to be, anyway to fix that?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff, of course you have the save so you cam easily use .width

Answer (score 80):

**Swift 4.2+**

Principle is:

1. Make sure delegation is set up (e.g. `collectionView.delegate = self`)
2. Implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` (it contains necessary method signature).
3. Call `collectionView...sizeForItemAt` method.
4. No need to bridge-cast `String` to `NSString` to call `size(withAttributes:` method. Swift `String` has it out of the box.
5. Attributes are the same you set for `(NS)AttributedString`, i.e. font family, size, weight, etc. Optional parameter.

---

Sample solution:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return "String".size(withAttributes: nil)
    }
}
```

But you would most likely want to specify concrete string attributes respective to your cell, hence final return would look like:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // dataArary is the managing array for your UICollectionView.
        let item = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        let itemSize = item.size(withAttributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        ])
        return itemSize
    }
}
```

**Why you SHOULD NOT use UILabel to calculate the size?**
Here's the suggested solution:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
label.text = textArray[indexPath.item]
label.sizeToFit()
```

Yes, you get same result. It looks simplistic and may seem as a go-to solution. But it's improper because:
1) it's expensive, 2) overhead and 3) dirty.

It's expensive because UILabel is a complex UI object, which is being created on every iteration whenever your cell is about to show even though you don't need it here.
It's an overhead solution because you only need to get *size* of a text, but you go as far as to create a whole UI object. And it's dirty for that reason.

Comment: don't forget to set `collectionView.delegate == self // or whatever-object-which-do-it`

Comment: Great answer. Although the size I was getting was a little bit smaller than it needed to be, on different lengths of strings, I decided to modify the size myself a bit. Adding additional 5 points to the width did the trick:
```CGSize(width: title.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)]).width + 5, height: 50)```

Comment: This was very good solution, thx so much. lots of love. I was implementing a custom segment bar and for that I used this code snippet.

Answer (score 45):

I have found a small trick for swift 4.2

For dynamic width & fixed height:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.text = textArray[indexPath.item]
        label.sizeToFit()
        return CGSize(width: label.frame.width, height: 32)
    }
```

For dynamic height & fixed width:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
            label.text = textArray[indexPath.item]
            label.sizeToFit()
            return CGSize(width: 120, height: label.frame.height)
        }
```

Comment: Be careful using this. Creating and drawing a new UILabel for each cell calculation is very expensive.

Comment: need add  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: To address the comment about this being expensive creating a dummy label, maybe you could just create one dummy label instead of several. All you really want from it is text size from label attributes. At the end of the day though, it is essentially the same as calculated the text size via `sizeWithAttributes`, so maybe that is the preferred answer.

Comment: @Hassan Thanks bro it worked for me, but i found a problem in width so added return CGSize(width: label.frame.width + 50, height: 32). Then it worked, i think this answer should be on top list.

Answer (score 27):

Checkout below code you might be giving very short CGSize.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *testString = @"SOME TEXT";
    return [testString sizeWithAttributes:NULL];
}
```

Comment: @Vineesh TP Thank you for your response, I'll definitely check it out and let you know!

Comment: +1000 This one definitely works. Yours and Basheer's post should have a green check mark together.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with swift 3?

Comment: Thank Man, its Party Time!!

Answer (score 25):

In Swift 5.X, this single line of code is enough.

In the below answer i have added dynamic width and static height. Based on your requirement change height value.

```
//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: itemsArray[indexPath.item].size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]).width + 25, height: 30)
}
```

Add **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** to your delegate

It's perfectly worked to me with **equal cell space with dynamic cell size based on text length**.

PFA image below...

[image]

Fix height of the collectionView (not cell )based on content(Dynamic height for collection view)

[How to adjust height of UICollectionView to be the height of the content size of the UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437966/how-to-adjust-height-of-uicollectionview-to-be-the-height-of-the-content-size-of/56802898#56802898)

Comment: The gapping between the cell varies. Do you have any solution to have a equal spacing between the cells?

Comment: I have added my collection view, please find it. I haven't observed any unequal cell spacing. First check your entire code, is there anything wrong If you want any help i will share the code send me your contact like mail or etc....

Comment: tirthendudass@gmail.com Please send your contact here.

Comment: @ iPeter, I shared already my code with you. Have you got? Is this helpful to you?

Comment: you saved my ass... but make sure to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` otherwise its never going to show any error neither changes are going to reflect ...

Comment: Fix height of the collectionView (not cell )based on content...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437966/how-to-adjust-height-of-uicollectionview-to-be-the-height-of-the-content-size-of/56802898#56802898

Answer (score 20):

In Swift 3

```
let size = (arrayOfStats[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(attributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4**

```
let size = (arrayOfStats[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(withAttributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

implement

```
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

and add a code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    label.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    label.sizeToFit()
    return CGSize(width: (label.frame.width+20), height: label.frame.size.height+20)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//add in view didload

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(self.breadScrumbCollectionView.frame.size.width, 30); 
self.breadScrumbCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one line for my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout()` did the trick for me:

```
collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work anymore or we can say this syntax is not valid.

Comment: This works but results in poor performance, at least it's noticeable when scrolling a large horizontal list

Answer (score 0):

//Create UICollectionView

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    //CollectionCellView width autoSize
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
   
    collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
   [enter image description here][1]
    return collectionView
}()
```