# UICollectionView with different cell size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, custom-collection

My goal is to create a `UICollectionView` with a layout as depicted below.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is this possible without creating a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`?

Comment: https://github.com/cp-satish-v/MosaicLayoutDemo

Answer (score 10):

Use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width : CGFloat
        let height : CGFloat

        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            width = 100
            height = 100
        } else {
            width = 50
            height = 50
        }
        return CGSizeMake(width, height)

}
```

Comment: Can you paste your cellforRowAtItem and numberOfItemsInSections delegate methods here?

Comment: Great , Working for me :)

Answer (score 5):

Without creating a custom layout of collection view it is not possible to achieve what you want.

You can create custom cell size using its delegate method `sizeforitematindexpath`.

Also, check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) link which helps to create a custom layout.

Comment: Okey, Still i am looking for simple way like scale cell size. custom layout is last option for me. Thank you

Comment: @Ujesh CollectionView is meant to be used with the layout. There is no other way you would achieve it. Else another way would be ScrollView + UIView which would make it difficult to manage things.

Answer (score 0):

many ways to do this below links.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34654076/5054123
- https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout
- https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout

Comment: i know about this library,  need simple Solution.  -> Is this possible without creating a custom UICollectionViewLayout?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Dejan Atanasov but for Swift 5

```
extension MainLobbyVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width : CGFloat
        let height : CGFloat
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            width = 100
            height = 100
        } else {
            width = 50
            height = 50
        }
        return CGSizeMake(width, height)
    }
}
```