# "No Such module as firebaseUI"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

[image: Imported the screenshot]    @import FirebaseUI;

When I imported this module it shows "No Such Module as FirebaseUI"

but I have already installed pods

```
 pod 'Firebase/Core'

 pod 'FirebaseUI'

 pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'

 pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'

 pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'

 pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'

 pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
```

I am new to ios can someone please help me

Comment: it may depend on a target. If you have more than one target in your project then it may happen that you've installed the pod for one of your targets and building a different one now

Comment: sorry I can't understand will you explain it briefly

Comment: Can you post the entire content of your Podfile?

Comment: I have already posted all my installed pod above...

Comment: No. Not only the list of pods but the whole content of the file. Just copy paste all the content from the file here

Comment: I didn't do anything just imported header modules and it throws an error no module found

Comment: Yes, I know. And I had an issue like that a week ago. And it was because I was building a different target. So it may be the case for you. Why don't you post the Podfile as I told you?

Comment: But I have only one target file @AndreyChernukha

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'CustomFirebaseUI' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for CustomFirebaseUI

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
#
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'



end

Comment: Above is my entire pod file

Comment: @RKios try to clean project and check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since FirebaseUI 11.0.0 it is no longer possible to import FirebaseUI framework using just:

```
import FirebaseUI
```

in Swift and

```
@import FirebaseUI
```

in Objective C.

According to the [official changelog](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/releases) at github.com, now you have to import FirebaseUI modules separately.

Example below (Swift):

```
//FirebaseUI 11.0
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseDatabaseUI
//...
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
```

Then add the following import to the problematic file:

```
import FirebaseStorageUI
```

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded FirebaseUI.framework from https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/releases

Dragged FirebaseUI.framework into my project

```
@import FirebaseUI
```

or use

```
#import <FirebaseUI/FirebaseUI.h>
```

Simply build your application (cmd - b) and it should resolve the issue.

Or

Make sure you are opening the .workspace file that is created when you install the pod's rather than the normal .xcode file.

Project -> Clean 
Also try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 2):

In the case where you are certain that the pod has been installed and the `.framework` file exists, you can try to delete the Derived Data and run a clean build. If you are running on an external device, sometimes deleting the application and then rebuilding it will help.

You can also try running `pod outdated` in a Terminal window to see if your FirebaseUI pod should be upgraded to a newer version.

Comment: Sure enough - simply **deleting derived data** did the trick. Annoying, right? Thanks!